# Are there any Open Source X400 Message Parsing Libraries

Tags: parsing, email

I'm working with an application that currently parses SMTP messages. In the future, I might be asked to add parsing for [X400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.400) messages. Are there any open-source libraries for parsing X400 messages that I could use? Or do I have to write my own parser?